# Connection failure mySQL for Excel 1.3.8

Tags: mysql, excel, ssl

I'm trying to connect and get this error:

"A possible fail reason could be that your user requires a SSL connection that is not currently supported.
Please check with the Administrator if you require a SSL Connection and if he can authorize your user to login without a SSL connection."

I manage to connect using Workbench with the same parameters

Comment: So is there a problem or not if you "manage to connect using Workbench with the same parameters"?

Comment: that is somewhat not much information, see if you folowed  the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows.html and how to use it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-wordexcel.html